# Avoid newline when combining two variables and outputing to file

Tags: bash, echo, cat

I am trying to run such sh script to gather geo information about Ip addresses. inputfile.txt is just a one column file with ip addresses in it.

Here is a sample of my input file:

```
213.100.122.171
213.100.126.188
213.100.129.186
213.100.18.247
213.100.23.238
213.100.26.151
```

Here is the code that I am using:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
output=outputfile.csv
for  i in $( cat "inputfile.txt"); 
do echo -e "$i,"$( geoiplookup -f /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat $i | cut -d' ' -f6,8-9)"" >> $output;
done
```

When I run this file, the result is like this

```
213.100.126.188
,LV, N/A, N/A,
213.100.129.186
,SE, N/A, N/A,
213.100.18.247
,LV, N/A, N/A,
213.100.23.238
,LV, N/A, N/A
```

I want them to be in each own line, like

```
213.100.126.188,LV, N/A, N/A,
213.100.129.186,SE, N/A, N/A,
213.100.18.247,LV, N/A, N/A,
213.100.23.238,LV, N/A, N/A,
```

Where i am wrong with my script?

Comment: You're wrong in many places: `for i in $(cat "inputfile.txt"); do` is wrong. What is the content of `inputfile.txt`? By the way, go and complain to the person who showed you this. Really do it. You're having `$(geoiplookup ...)` unquoted. This is bad (subject to pathname expansion). You're using an unquoted variable `$i` there too. You're opening and closing the file `outputfile.csv` for each ip, this is just uselessly resource consuming. Put your redirection at the end of the loop. Of course, none of these solve your problem!

Answer (score 1):

Using a `for` loop with `cat` is not a good way to process a file line by line. I would recommend changing your script to something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

output=outputfile.csv    
while read -r line; do
    echo -e "$line, $( geoiplookup -f /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat "$line" | cut -d' ' -f6,8-9)"
done < inputfile.txt > "$output"
```

This will truncate the output file and write all of the output of the loop to it. Enclosing the command substitution as well as the parameter expansion in double quotes prevents issues with expansion of characters in the output of the command.

Comment: Unfortunately, the result is the same :/

Comment: As [gniourf_gniourf has mentioned above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28499766/avoid-newline-when-combining-two-variables-and-outputing-to-file#comment45319276_28499766), it would be useful to see the contents of your input file. Perhaps you could edit your question to include a sample of its contents

Comment: Added with example. there are only one column in file with ip addreses. Nothing more.

Comment: @jam what system are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Its most probably that application `geoiplookup` that produces the newline. So you have to pipe the output trough `sed` to remove it:

```
for  i in $( cat "inputfile.txt"); 
  do echo -e "$i,"$( geoiplookup -f /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat $i | \
  cut -d' ' -f6,8-9 | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/)"" >> $output;
done
```

Comment: The newline after the command substitution is desired. It is the one from trying to read the file line by line using `for` with `cat` that is causing the problem.

Comment: Bash strips all trailing newlines with `$(...)`, so this can't be the answer. Try it: `a=$(echo test; echo; echo; echo; echo; echo); declare -p a`. You'll see no trailing newlines. Besides, since the `$(...)` is outside of the quotes, Bash will strip any newlines altogether. I can safely say that you're doubly wrong here. (But I'm not the downvoter!).

Comment: @TomFenech I have a file called `input` with 3 lines, doing `for  i in $( cat "input");  do echo -e "-$i-"; done` prints all the lines without a newline after `$i`. If the file has `\n` at the end `echo -e` will interpret them as newlines, but not in our case. Do I understand something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found the problem. The input file had an empty first line and the script somehow decided to work as I decribed. When I deleted that empty line, everything worked fine.